# React Native navigation - undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation

I'm new to React native and trying to follow tutorials to learn however can't get navigation between screens to work. I have previously got it working fine with one screen but when adding navigation I get errors.

Following this: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/navigation.html

Gives me code like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StackNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
  };
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <Button
        title="Go to Jane's profile"
        onPress={() =>
          navigate('Profile', { name: 'Jane' })
        }
      />
    );
  }
}

class ProfileScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Profile',
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Button title="do nothing"/>
    );
  }
}

const App = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },
});
```

Trying to run this (through the expo app) results in the error

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')

So am I doing navigation correctly and how do I fix this error?

Comment: Where are u rendering the `<App/>`

Comment: can you show your index.ios.js file where you call 
`AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyAwesomeApp', () => App);`

Comment: Do you have a constructor in your HomeScreen component? Maybe you are not able to access props. Read this: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#constructor

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AppRegistry.registerComponent in your App.
A nice way of doing this is to create a src directory and then create the 2 js files, HomeScreen and ProfileScreen there. Then create and App.js on the same level as your index.android.js or index.ios.js and include these 2 files and declare the StackNavigator as you did in your code, but instead of **const App** you need to have **const NameOfYourApp**, where NameOfYourApp is how you named your project when you ran create-react-native-app.(If it is App, just leave it like that)
Then you need to add this line at the end, AppRegistry.registerComponent('NameOfYourApp', () => NameOfYourApp);

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StackNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';
import HomeScreen from './src/HomeScreen'
import ProfileScreen from './src/ProfileScreen'

const NameOfYourApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },
});
AppRegistry.registerComponent('NameOfYourApp', () => NameOfYourApp)
```

The final step is to import your App.js file in your index.android.js or index.ios.js

```
import './App';
```